# Creating an array from variable names

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller, symfony

When writing controllers for Symfony 2, I often need to pass quite a few variables to the template like `return array('param1' => $param1, 'anotherBigParam' => $anotherBigParam, 'yetAnotherParam' => $yetAnotherParam);`

With many parameters this ends up really long and ugly, so I thought about creating a helper function for it:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $param1 = 'fee';
    $anotherBigParam = 'foe';
    $yetAnotherParam = 'fum';
    return $this->vars('param1', 'anotherBigParam', 'yetAnotherParam');
}

private function vars() {
    $arr = array();
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        $arr[$arg] = $$arg;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Is there some kind of drawback or risk from doing this? Does PHP or Symfony 2 already provide a better or cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`compact`](http://php.net/compact).

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $param1 = 'fee';
    $anotherBigParam = 'foe';
    $yetAnotherParam = 'fum';
    return compact('param1', 'anotherBigParam', 'yetAnotherParam');
}
```

Comment: I *knew* there had to be a native way! Thanks for both of the answers, I'll accept this one for it's ninja speed as soon as accepting becomes possible.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja: PHP's got tons of built-in functions :-P

Comment: @Rocket: True, it's a haystack of useful built-in functions and finding the right ones can be really challenging if it's a rarely needed one. I read through the list of array functions but skipped `compact` because it sounded more like it has something to do with compression...

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja: Yeah, some functions have interesting names.  Like `explode`/`implode`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a native way of doing it: [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

```
$one = 'ONE';
$two = 'TWO';
$a = compact( 'one', 'two' );
print_r( $a );
/*
Array
(
    [one] => ONE
    [two] => TWO
)
*/
```